# Linear dependence of functions of t

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $\ \vec x_1=(e^t,te^t)$ and $\vec x_2=(1,t)$. Show that they are linearly dependent at each point $t\in [0,1]$. Nevertheless, show that they are linearly independent on $t\in [0,1]$.

Attempt: I am a bit confused about this problem. I calculate the determinant of $(\vec x_1 \; \vec x_2)$ and get zero which proves that these vectors are linearly dependent. I don't know how to go about proving that they are linearly independent on the same interval. Help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointwise is not uniform.

You get pointwise nontrivial linear combinations, but the coefficients depend on $t$.

If you take a linear combination on $[0,1]$, you will easily see that it must be trivial.

Indeed, if $\lambda x_1(t)+\mu x_2(t)=0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$, we get
$$
\lambda e^t+\mu=0\qquad\lambda te^t+\mu t=0\qquad\forall t\in[0,1].
$$

Try to take $t=0$ in the lhs, and then $t=1$ in the rhs.